# How do I remove duplicate records from a table, but leave the latest?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to clean up my table by removing duplicates in the table but leave the latest version of the duplicate records.

My table looks similar to the one below. I would like to remove the flightNo "AF 8253" duplicate, but leave the flightNo "AF 8253" with arrival time at 14:20.

```
id  depOrArriv flightNo airline   dest  origin  depature  arrivalTime  status
183 Arrival    AF 8253  AirUganda NULL  Nairobi NULL      14:05        Scheduled
184 Arrival    AF 8253  AirUganda NULL  Nairobi NULL      14:20        Scheduled
185 Arrival    SCAN09   SCAN Air  NULL  Kampala NULL      10:30        Scheduled
```

I have tried the code below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    $sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE schedule_temp AS 
              SELECT DISTINCT * FROM sortedArrivals 
              DELETE FROM sortedArrivals
              INSERT INTO sortedArrivals( 
                 timePeriod, depOrArriv, flightNo, airline, dest, 
                 origin, depature, don, arrivalTime, status) 
              SELECT timePeriod, depOrArriv, flightNo, airline, 
                 dest, origin, depature, don, arrivalTime, status 
              FROM schedule_temp";

if (!$mysqli->query($sql))
  {
    die('Error: ' . $mysqli->error);

  }
```

Can anyone kindly help point me in the right direction?
Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: You don't anything about SQL? And you didn't list your duplicate flight in the example.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work"??? it *seems* to be gibberish from start to finish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with this, assuming a rescheduled flight always have a higher **RowID** than the previous one, and you can identify a duplicate by having the same **flightNo**, **airline** and **origin** (you can also add more variable to the GROUP BY clause in other case):

```
DELETE FROM sortedArrivals 
WHERE RowId NOT IN 
(SELECT MAX(RowId) FROM sortedArrivals GROUP BY flightNo, airline, origin);
```

Comment: Beautiful and logical solution. Thank you very much, your code helped resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a SQL fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7e36/1

```
create table flight (id varchar(100), arrivalTime varchar(100));
insert into flight values ('8253','14:05');
insert into flight values ('8253','14:20');
insert into flight values ('8254','15:05');
insert into flight values ('8254','15:20');

DELETE FROM flight
WHERE not exists (
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT f2.ID
      , MAX(f2.arrivalTime) arrivalTime
   FROM flight f2
 GROUP BY f2.ID) x
WHERE x.ID = flight.ID and x.arrivalTime = flight.arrivalTime
);  

SELECT * from flight;
```

Output:

```
ID      ARRIVALTIME
8253    14:20
8254    15:20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (flightNo VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 ,arrivalTime  TIME NOT NULL
 ,PRIMARY KEY (flightno,arrivaltime)
 );
 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 ('AF 8253','14:05'),        
 ('AF 8253','14:20'),
 ('SCAN09','10:30');

 SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +----------+-------------+
 | flightNo | arrivalTime |
 +----------+-------------+
 | AF 8253  | 14:05:00    |
 | AF 8253  | 14:20:00    |
 | SCAN09   | 10:30:00    |
 +----------+-------------+


  DELETE a 
    FROM my_table a
    LEFT
    JOIN 
       ( SELECT x.* 
           FROM my_table x
           JOIN 
              ( SELECT flightno
                     , MAX(arrivaltime) max_arrivaltime 
                  FROM my_table 
                 GROUP BY flightno
              ) y 
             ON y.flightno = x.flightno 
            AND y.max_arrivaltime = x.arrivaltime
       ) b
      ON b.flightno = a.flightno
     AND b.arrivaltime = a.arrivaltime
   WHERE b.flightno IS NULL;

 SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +----------+-------------+
 | flightNo | arrivalTime |
 +----------+-------------+
 | AF 8253  | 14:20:00    |
 | SCAN09   | 10:30:00    |
 +----------+-------------+
```

Comment: I tried your solution but failed to get it to work. What's with the X, a's and b's in your query? Kindly elaborate.

Comment: My table and yours appear to be identical in every relevant detail, so I fail to see why it wouldn't work. x, a, and b are all table aliases. BTW, the accepted solution is definitely NOT beautiful! ;-)

Comment: Sorry the X, A, and B is confusing. Would it work if I copied and pasted it into my MySQL query? Thank you.